# Create an expanding horizontal UIStackView with selectable buttons in two states in UIKit

Tags: swift, user-interface, uikit, uibutton

I want to create a horizontal UIStackView containing 5 buttons. Each button can be in one of two states: selected or unselected. When a button is unselected, it appears as a square containing only an image. When a button is selected, it displays both an image and a label, transforming it into a rectangle longer than the other unselected buttons.

When the view is initially set up, the first button should be in the selected state. Tapping on any other button should cause the previously selected button to shrink back to a square, while the newly tapped button expands to display the label. How can I achieve this behavior using UIKit?

Below you can see an actual image that explain visually what I described above:

[image]

I thought about using button.changesSelectionAsPrimaryAction = true introduced in iOS 15 - to avoid creating a subclass of UIButton. Unfortunately the button's appearance will automatically be updated for the selected state, which includes a different background color and a checkmark image so it might not be suitable for this case. I was wondering if was possible achieving this design without creating a custom UIButton class at all.

Comment: You could try a HStackView with 5 HStackViews containing an Image : String. Then animate the Show/Hide of the Strings on select of the corresponding image. 

One issue will be the rounded background on selected. If you have the spacing of the Image:String HStack to zero. Then have both image and String background set on selected, with specific rounded corners. That could work.

Comment: @OneCommentMan Interesting approach! Thanks for the prompt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Swift / UIKit (this does not apply to SwiftUI)...

We can take advantage of `UIStackView` auto-resizing when arranged subviews are shown and hidden.

We'll start with a `UIView` subclass (instead of a button), that will contain:

- a "background" view (with rounded corners)
- a horizontal stack view, containing

  - an image view
  - a label
- a tap gesture recognizer to toggle its "selected" state

When we want to "expand" that view we set `label.isHidden = false`, and to "collapse" it we set `label.isHidden = true`.

If we have five of those custom views as arranged subviews of a "parent" horizontal stack view, all of the sizing will be automatic.

So, our custom "Image and Label" view:

```
class ImageLabelView: UIView {
    
    let imgView = UIImageView()
    let label = UILabel()
    let bkgView = UIView()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder:aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        
        let stack = UIStackView()
        stack.spacing = 8
        
        [imgView, label].forEach { v in
            stack.addArrangedSubview(v)
        }
        
        bkgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(bkgView)

        stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(stack)
        
        let pad: CGFloat = 8.0
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            bkgView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            bkgView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            bkgView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            bkgView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),

            stack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: pad),
            stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: pad),
            stack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -pad * 2.0),
            stack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -pad),
            
            imgView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 32.0),
            imgView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView.heightAnchor),
            
        ])
        
        bkgView.layer.cornerRadius = 12
        bkgView.backgroundColor = .black.withAlphaComponent(0.2)
        
        label.textColor = .white
        label.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
        
        self.clipsToBounds = true
    }
    
    public var selected: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            // we only want to animate things if we are already a subview
            if superview == nil {
                self.label.isHidden = !self.selected
                self.bkgView.alpha = self.selected ? 1.0 : 0.0
            } else {
                self.label.isHidden = !self.selected
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                    self.bkgView.alpha = self.selected ? 1.0 : 0.0
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Next, a `UIView` subclass (let's call it `WeatherTabView`) with:

- horizontal stack view containing 5 `ImageLabelView`
- code to populate those 5 views with images and text
- tap gesture handler
- and a "callback closure" so we can inform the controller that an item was selected

  class WeatherTabView: UIView {

  ```
    public var tapCallback: ((Int) -> ())?

    private let stateStack = UIStackView()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder:aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {

        stateStack.distribution = .equalSpacing
        stateStack.alignment = .center

        stateStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(stateStack)

        let pad: CGFloat = 8.0

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stateStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: pad),
            stateStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: pad),
            stateStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -pad),
            stateStack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -pad),
        ])

        let names: [String] = [
            "Sun", "Storm", "Tornado", "Moon", "Snow"
        ]
        for (i, s) in names.enumerated() {
            guard let img = UIImage(named: "t\(i+1)") else {
                fatalError("Could not load image!")
            }
            let v = ImageLabelView()
            v.imgView.image = img
            v.label.text = s
            v.selected = i == 0
            stateStack.addArrangedSubview(v)
            let tp = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(gotTap(_:)))
            v.addGestureRecognizer(tp)
        }

        self.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0
        self.backgroundColor = .black.withAlphaComponent(0.20)

    }

    @objc func gotTap(_ tp: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let v = tp.view,
              let idx = stateStack.arrangedSubviews.firstIndex(of: v)
        else { return }

        tapCallback?(idx)

        stateStack.arrangedSubviews.forEach { sv in
            if let sv = sv as? ImageLabelView {
                sv.selected = v == sv
            }
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                self.layoutIfNeeded()
            })
        }
    }
  ```

  }

and a simple view controller to demonstrate:

```
class TestVC: UIViewController {
    
    let weatherTabView = WeatherTabView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        
        weatherTabView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(weatherTabView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            weatherTabView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 100.0),
            weatherTabView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            weatherTabView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
        ])
    
        // setup the closure
        weatherTabView.tapCallback = { [weak self] idx in
            print("Item \(idx) was tapped!")
            // do something
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Looks like this when running:

[image]

Note: This is ***Example Code Only!!!*** -- but it should get you started...

Comment: It's a sound example! Thanks for sharing